# Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown closes the main thread c#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am opening a wpf UI in a separate thread using

```
helperThread = new Thread(() =>
{
     //ShowHelpInDialog(e.Url, -1, -1, -1, -1, e.HelpContext);
     //System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
     dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ShowHelpInDialog(e.Url, -1, -1, -1, -1, e.HelpContext)));

});
helperThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
helperThread.IsBackground = true;
helperThread.Start();
```

During dialog close event, I am calling

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

which is causing main thread/Application to close, Which i don't want.

I don't want my parent application to close.

Comment: Good formatting is always your friend.

Comment: What did you expect BeginInvokeShutdown to do exactly?

Comment: I am using BeginInvokeShutdown to release the memory.

Comment: You're not actually opening your UI in a separate thread. Your `new Thread` immediately calls `dispatcher.Invoke`, which pushes you back to (most likely) your main thread.  Remove the `dispatcher.Invoke` and try just calling `ShowHelpInDialog` directly from your new thread.

Answer (score 1):

Please observe the following example on how to open a new `Window` from another thread:

```
private void NewWindowHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start();
}

private void ThreadStartingPoint()
{
    Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
    tempWindow.Show();       
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

> From the Multiple Windows, Multiple Threads section of the [`Threading Model`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-11) page at MSDN.

UPDATE >>>

This code is 100% tested and will definitely open a new `Window` in a new thread. If you don't want to shut down the other `Window`, then don't call the `BeginInvokeShutdown` method which will shut the `Window` down. You're calling it on `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` which is running on the MAIN thread (where the `MainWindow.xaml` is running).

Comment: I just followed the same but still closes the parent dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to invoke `BeginInvokeShutdown` on the dialog's `Dispatcher` not on `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`.

Your dialog closed event handler should look like this:

```
dialog.Closed += (sender, e) => dialog.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown();
```